# Can I use "Arial Rounded MT Bold" with css?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

Can I use "Arial Rounded MT Bold" with css ?

```
font-family:"Arial Rounded MT Bold", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
```

Nothing Changed when I put :

```
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
```

Comment: What do you mean by nothing changed? And <rant>why are more people using the `coding-style` tag for CSS questions?</rant>

Comment: @BoltClock: What should we use?

Comment: @JamWaffles The `coding-style` tag is for "Conventions and practices used in software. Naming classes, variables, and files are examples as is organization of code."

Comment: @JamWaffles: Just `css` will do in most cases. `coding-style` is not about page styles in terms of CSS code, but about the style in which we write any kind of code.

Comment: I have the same problem. Apparently Chrome fails to find any font family ending with the word "Bold" even if it is installed on the client PC.

Comment: Comments here are a very good example of why people say Stackoverflow is a hostile environment. I will probably be on someone's blacklist for saying that, while those who made an issue over a quite petty matter about the use of the editor will probably be excused or applauded for standing up for "the way we do things here". Sometimes that is important and really matters. Way to often, it doesn't matter at all and comes off as arrogant and petty.

Answer (score 28):

Google Fonts has Nunito, by Vernon Adams:

http://www.google.com/webfonts/family?family=Nunito

It's nice and rounded; sort of reminds me of what they're using on Glitch.

Comment: I came to this page after googling for a Google Web Fonts alternative to Arial Rounded MT Bold. Thanks to you I was not disappointed.

Answer (score 6):

It's hard to know without more information from the OP but I've seen these same symptoms caused by the hardware acceleration feature in Firefox. It's been know to cause several problems with [font rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055436/firefox-hardware-acceleration-causing-css-issues). One I've observed is failing to render a non-standard font (such as "Arial MT Rounded Bold") despite it being present on the client machine.

For example, this page...

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body { font-family: "Arial Rounded MT Bold"; font-size: 30px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    This can be really annoying.
</body>
</html>
```

When viewed in IE, Chrome or FF with hardware acceleration turned off the font appears correctly, like this...

[image: FF 10 with hardware acceleration turned off]

But when viewed in FF with hardware acceleration enabled the browser fails to "find" the specified font so it defaults to another, like this...

[image: FF 10 with hardware acceleration turned on]

There have been issues with this "feature" of FF since version 4.

Probably the best solution is to either use a different (standard) font or (as Kent suggests) find a similar web font that will work in all modern browsers. Alternatively, like many font issues, the problem can be mitigated by supplying a list of font families to use as fall-backs.

Comment: I think part of the annoying "feature" you're describing is because your sample CSS doesn't specify any fallback fonts after the first one so it goes straight back to Times New Roman. I appreciate that you seem to be saying it incorrectly can't find the font in accelerated mode but you could provide better second, third etc choices.

Comment: @rtpHarry: My example is constructed specifically to illustrate the problem not work around it. Besides, I addressed the use of fallbacks in my original answer.

Comment: Yeah you made a good point, I was just adding to the conversation :)

Answer (score 6):

I've seen an alternative Google Font suggested here from back in 2011 which is a pretty good match but there are some thin parts to the font which aren't the same as the Arial Rounded MT Bold.

For people still looking for an alternative I think this one is a better match; its called Varela Round by Joe Prince:

- [Varela Round](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Varela+Round)

I would also set it in `font-weight: bold;` for a more accurate match.

Answer (score 2):

To use custom fonts with good cross browser compatibility, take a look at [FontSquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/). They will generate the correct CSS to get custom fonts working cross browser. Take a look around their site for Rounded MT Bold or whatever else you want :-) Also, if you want more fonts, take a look at http://www.fontex.org/

Answer (score 1):

There's a good chance that — if nothing changed (on your local browser's rendering of the webpage) when you changed the font stack — that you don't actually have Arial MT Rounded Bold installed on your computer. One way to test this is to use Firebug, to 'inspect element' for the headline (or whatever the font is applied to), and to edit the font-family listing in the right-hand Firebug pane. (Usually, I just find the named font and add a space into the name of it, which "breaks" the call to the proper font, and the browser then moves on to the next font in the stack.)

Other options include using Google's web-font Nunito (as Kent Brewster recommended a few minutes ago), or setting up a font-face font on your own server, providing one of the rounded fonts (RockoFLF Bold, FF Din Rounded, Nunito, and Arial MT Rounded Bold are all options). (Technically, per Kent's comment, Glitch is using RockoFLF, with Arial MT Rounded Bold as the second font in the stack. At least, that's what they were doing a few months ago when I last looked at their code. ... Oh ... just checked again, and they've dropped the Arial MT Rounded Bold out of the stack. They're calling RockoFLF with an embedded font-face.)

Anyway, as Kent Brewster noted, I think your best bet is to use Google Web Fonts' 'Nunito', if you aren't sure that it'll be on your users' computers (or even your own).

Answer (score 1):

It may not appear because of system compatibility - you can check out Arial Rounded MT Bold on CSS Font Stack for compatibility. There's a 59.53% on Windows and 95.14% on Mac. https://www.cssfontstack.com/Arial-Rounded-MT-Bold

Answer (score 1):

Its worth noting that Linux doesn't come with Arial by default so one should not rely on a font being present on a users computer. Instead they should download the files (license permitting), host them on their site and link to them using @font-face.

Comment: This also applies to a "quite relevant" linux based OS named *Android* ... The main reason so called "Web-safe" fonts were never included in "non-MS-Apple" OS is that these have never been open-source (albeit free to use but still under a [propriatary licence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_fonts_for_the_Web)). Besides, the separate "Arial Rounded" family is not even included.

Answer (score 0):

[Google Fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts) is also a possibility. There are a lot of different fonts but I don't know whether there's exactly Arial Rounded MT Bold.

You can use only fonts which are installed at the clients computer!! So just mentioning them in the css font-family doesn't work if the font is not installed. For this, Google Fonts and others bring the functionality... so everytime you use a font that is not "Times", "Arial" or "Verdana", which are installed on nearly every computer, you should think about an alternative to raw css

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still having a problem getting Arial Rounded MT Bold to work in CSS try using "Arial Rounded MT" (no Bold) in your font-family declaration. It works for me. I assume somewhere in the font file it is called "Arial Rounded MT" instead of "Arial Rounded MT Bold". Probably because "Bold" would not normally be included in a font name as it's a `font-weight`.

So this:

```
font-family: "Arial Rounded MT";
```

Not this:

```
font-family: "Arial Rounded MT Bold";
```

Even without the "Bold" it is the correct font in the correct weight. Bolding it will have no effect.