# Why doesn't this font family work in Chome, Safari, Opera and IE < 9 but works in Firefox and IE9?

Tags: html, css, fonts

This works fine in Firefox and IE9

```
font-family: "Arial Rounded MT", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
```

But not in Chrome, Safari, IE 8 & 7 and Opera. In those browsers it defaults to just Arial.

Is there a way to use the arial rounded mt font in those browsers?

Note: I am testing this on the same computer which has the arial rounded mt font installed.

Comment: Do other fonts with whitespace work right for you? Plus, many of your visitors won't have that font anyway...

Comment: Isn't that a bold-only font? Try appending `Bold` to that name, making it `Arial Rounded MT Bold`.

Comment: @Tom van der Woerdt adding `Arial Rounded MT Bold` didn't work. @Anonymouse whitespace shouldn't be a problem since it's inside quotes, as for users not having that font, that's why the fallback arial is there.

Comment: The question's css works in FF 8.0 and in IE 9 (in IE9 document/browser mode) for me. It doesn't work in IE8 or lower modes, nor in Chrome 15, unless I use @TomvanderWoerdt's suggestion (appending "Bold") then it works in Chrome too. (Windows 7)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512720/can-i-use-arial-rounded-mt-bold-with-css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using it's postscript name - though it's off spec, some browsers will use it anyway (I know for sure Safari does, not sure about the others).

In this case, the ps name is `ArialRoundedMTBold`, so try:

```
font-family: ArialRoundedMTBold, "Arial Rounded MT Bold", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
```

Comment: Thanks this does work although I ended up not using it since this particular font looks way too bold in webkit browsers (chrome + safari) as compared to ff or ie. Also using this kills the font in those other 2 browsers, so if anyone uses this I would assume some sort of browser specific hack should be used to attach this style to webkit browsers only.

Comment: To be honest, it's not the nicest font anyway! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use un-web friendly fonts then other users who visit your website will not see the fonts unless they are installed on their computer as well.

You are best by looking into using either...

[Font Face](http://www.css3.info/preview/web-fonts-with-font-face/)

Or

[Cufon](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/)

...as these will allow all visitors to your website to see your custom fonts.